# Center floated child DIVs in a parent DIV that has fluid width

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
     <div class="child">Box1</div>
     <div class="child">Box2</div>
     <div class="child">Box3</div>
     <div class="child">Box4</div>
     <div class="child">Box5</div>
     <div class="child">Box6</div>
     <div class="child">Box7</div>
     <div class="child">Box8</div>
     <div class="child">Box9</div>
     <div class="child">Box10</div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#parent {
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 1000px;
   height: 500px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   text-align: center;
}
.child {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   margin: 10px;
   float: left;
}
```

I want to float left the child DIVs and at the same time center them in the parent DIV that does't have a fixed width.

The reason I don't want to use display: inline-block for the child DIVs is that if a row has only 1 or 2 boxes , they will be centred and i want them to be aligned to the left with the boxes on the previous rows.

The second reason is that more data will be loaded using ajax. So, if the last row has only 1 or 2 boxes and still can accommodate more boxes, they will be inserted into a new line instead of being appended to the last row. I'm not sure of this point but I think that what would happen when using display inline-block. Float instead doesn't have this behaviour.

Forgot to mention that the parent should be display: inline-block because another box will be aligned next to it.

I created a fiddle for you to play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/6a2eqpmu/

Comment: @Pete I worked on a similar problem last year and indeed, you need a JS assisted solution.  The crux of the problem is that once elements are floated, the elements no longer factor into computing the width of the parent width.  You have a solution, you may as well post it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are unable to do this using pure css.  If you are willing to use a bit of javascript and jQuery you can easily achieve what you want:

```
var parent = $('#parent'),
    container = $('#container'),
    children = container.children('.child'),
    width = children.eq(0).outerWidth() + parseInt(children.eq(0).css('margin-left')) + parseInt(children.eq(0).css('margin-right')),
    maxWidth = children.length * width;

function resizeContainer() {
    var newWidth = Math.floor(parent.width() / width) * width;
    if (newWidth <= maxWidth && newWidth > 0) {
        container.width(newWidth);
    }
}

$(window).resize(resizeContainer);

resizeContainer();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6a2eqpmu/18/)

Comment: Extra clarification why it cannot be done with CSS alone: **http://jsfiddle.net/6a2eqpmu/20/**. The container is centered, and the childs are floating left within the container, all as it should... But the container doesn't resize (become smaller) if a child gets bumped to the next row, because as far as the container is concerned, its preferred width is still that of all childs next to each other on one row, and that's what it resizes to.

Comment: I have come up with a pure css way to do this that uses a lot of media queries but requires you to know how many boxes you have and apply it to the parent container as a class (using some server side code or hardcoded if your page is fllat html): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876653/css-centering-dynamic-div/28876722#answer-28876722.  Seems like a lot of css, but if you are using something like sass it would be very simple to write a loop to cover these styles and on a live site I'm guessing the boxes would be wider than 100px so you should need less queries

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `margin: 0 auto;` to #parent. This will center the parent div when the document width is over 1000px wide.

Comment: Question is about to align childs, not parent's itself.

Comment: that would work but i totally forgot that the parent also has a box aligned next to it so i have to use display inline-block for the parent which would make margin:0 auto; do nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

If your parent element doesn't have a fixed width you can't center his child elements with only CSS. I think you have to write some script that calculate the parent width, every row width and set to them the properly margin-right and margin-left.

Answer (score 0):

text-align works on inline elements. If I understand your problem, you should remove the float and put the boxes in display:inline-block.

Something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/6a2eqpmu/7/

```
#parent {
   max-width: 1500px;
   height: 500px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   text-align: center;
}
.child {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 10px;
    display:inline-block; 
}
```

I added html comments to avoid the white-space problem, and put a max-width of 1500px in order to see the boxes centered.

Comment: read carefully the question, author doesn't want center everything

Comment: so what does that mean ? "I want to float left the child DIVs and at the same time center them in the parent DIV that does't have a fixed width." It's not really clear for me :)

Comment: My bad, i didn't focus on the rest of the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add invisible placeholders to the end of your ***inline*** blocks. That will left-align the last row.

http://jsfiddle.net/aakt65x4/

If you don't fill up the first row, the entire thing will appear left-aligned. But I think that's what you want.

**HTML:**

```
<!--
  Centers a group of boxes that wrap to the width of its container.
  Also left-aligns them inside the container.
  Issue: Does not center group if there aren't enough boxes to fill
  the first row.
  -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>

    <!--
      How many placeholders do you need?
      At least the number of blocks minus two.
      -->
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    text-align: center;     /* center a max-width container */
    font-size: 0;           /* remove spaces between blocks */
}
.container {                /* you don't need this */
    background-color: #eee; /* so you can see what's happening */
    max-width: 960px;       /* to demonstrate the centering of a max-width container */
    display: inline-block;  /* center the max-width container */
    text-align: center;     /* center the group of blocks */
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;  /* left-align within the group */
    background-color: red;  /* so you can see what's happening */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.placeholder {
    display: inline-block;  /* add to the line of blocks */
    width: 120px;           /* width + margin of a block */
}
```