# css centering dynamic div

Tags: html, css, dynamic, center

I have a div #content where i on the run add left floated divs #block and there are divs with fixed width on either side of div (a) , #lcontent and #rcontent
How do i get #content to remain at center when side divs have dynamic height and #content changes over time

content should remain in center wether there are 2,3,4 or 100 #block inside it. But the #block should always be on the left of #content

Only #lcontent, #rcontent and #block have fixed width
[image: What i want to show up on web]

html code

```
<div id="contentcontainer">
    <div id="lcontent"></div>
    <div id="mcontent">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="block"></div>
            <div id="block"></div>
            <div id="block"></div>
            <div id="Block"></div>
            <div id="Block"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rcontent"></div>
</div>
```

css code

```
#lcontent
{
float: left;
width: 100px;
min-width: 100px;
min-height: 100px;
background: lightblue;   
}
#rcontent
{
float: right;
width: 100px;
background: lightblue;
}
#mcontent
{
background: lightgrey;
float: right;
right: 50%;
position: relative;
}
#content 
{
float: right;
right: -50%;
position: relative;
background: green;
min-height: 200px;
text-align: center;
}
#block
{
margin: 5px;
width: 300px;
border: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;½ 
height: 150px;   
}
```

Comment: share your code / demo?

Comment: Did you heard about http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ especially masonary mode http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be very difficult using pure css and will need you to know the 
number of boxes that the container is going to have (and add a class to the parent depending on it) - which if this is dynamic content then you should have a server side language for this.  You will also need a hell of a lot of media queries:

```css
.container {
    text-align:center;
}
.centered {
    text-align:left;
    margin:auto;
}
.block {
    margin:3px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.seven {max-width:770px;} /* this is the number of block * their outer width (margin + border + padding + width) */

/*one block*/
@media (max-width:219px) { /* this is the width of 2 blocks outer width -1px (you may need to add the width of the left and right column to this plus any left and right padding of the center column.  This is really the max width of the container div */
    .centered {
        width:110px; /* the outer width of a block */
    }
}

/*two blocks*/
/* keep adding media queries to either your max number of blocks or the largest screen size you want to support */
/*min width is 2 * 1 block outer width, max width is 3 * 1 block outer width - 1px*/
@media (min-width:220px) and (max-width:329px) {
    .centered {
        width:220px; /* the outer width of 2 blocks */
    }
}
@media (min-width:330px) and (max-width:439px) {
    .centered {
        width:330px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:440px) and (max-width:549px) {
    .centered {
        width:440px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:550px) and (max-width:659px) {
    .centered {
        width:550px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:660px) and (max-width:769px) {
    .centered {
        width:660px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:770px) and (max-width:879px) {
    .centered {
        width:770px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:880px) and (max-width:989px) {
    .centered {
        width:880px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:990px) and (max-width:1100px) {
    .centered {
        width:990px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="centered seven"><!--the seven class is the number of children blocks-->
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8wbtmys2/1/)

[Otherwise you can try a js solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181090/center-floated-child-divs-in-a-parent-div-that-has-fluid-width/26181316#26181316)

Comment: The following will happen if i do that.
First line has 3 #block which are centered, second line has 2 #block which are also centered. And the blocks on line 2 should be located below the first 2 blocks on line 1.
Furthermore when parent contains more blocks than can be on one line the entire parent (#content) is pushed down below #rcontent and #lcontent

Comment: I dont like @media solution. But i do like the fiddle solution.
I have actually tried emplementing it but first of all my CONTENT is empty when the page loads. It is populated through DOM so i cant get variables when it loads. Then i tried setting the variables everytime i add objects to CONTENT but i just get width = 0 and newWidth = NaN

Comment: is it being added to a div that has display:none; or visibility: hidden?  if so the width will always be 0

Comment: No unfortunately it isnt

I just tried the following code which should be the same as the fiddle exmaple but it doesnt work. Perhaps someone can tell me what i am doing wrong. I have the code on http://heboit.dk/test/test.html , as you can see the blocks aren centered in the container

Comment: ok, you need to wrap the js code in document.ready (or move it to the bottom of the page).  If it is in the header like that, nothing in the dom will have rendered which is probably why your width is 0

Comment: Thank you. It helped to move the fiddle js code to the bottom of the html file. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add invisible placeholders to the end of your inline blocks. That will left-align the last row.

http://jsfiddle.net/aakt65x4/

However, if you don't fill up the first row, the entire thing will appear left-aligned. But I think that's what you want, right?

**HTML:**

```
<!--
  Centers a group of boxes that wrap to the width of its container.
  Also left-aligns them inside the container.
  Issue: Does not center group if there aren't enough boxes to fill
  the first row.
  -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>

    <!--
      How many placeholders do you need?
      At least the number of blocks minus two.
      -->
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
    <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    text-align: center;     /* center a max-width container */
    font-size: 0;           /* remove spaces between blocks */
}
.container {                /* you don't need this */
    background-color: #eee; /* so you can see what's happening */
    max-width: 960px;       /* to demonstrate the centering of a max-width container */
    display: inline-block;  /* center the max-width container */
    text-align: center;     /* center the group of blocks */
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;  /* left-align within the group */
    background-color: red;  /* so you can see what's happening */
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.placeholder {
    display: inline-block;  /* add to the line of blocks */
    width: 120px;           /* width + margin of a block */
}
```